# Unable to open BCC

Tags: jboss, atg

I am currently doing a project in ATG 10.2 with JBoss 5.1.0 as server.When I try to open BCC using url: http://localhost:8080/atg/bcc ,it is showing 404 error.

Comment: Are you running the BCC on the same JBoss instance as your Storefront (Commerce) instance? If so, which ports does that run on?

Comment: Could we please get a full log, including everything from initial startup?